# How to Display a Geotiff image using Python

Tags: python-2.7, geospatial, gdal, rasterio

I am new to Python2.7 and have tried installing rasterio,using wheel file,but still the following error comes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import rasterio
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: I'm guessing you installed the wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ Did you also install the gdal wheels and the VCredist SP1 provided there? I'd personally recommend using the Anaconda python distribution, which includes a nice package manager that makes satisfying your dependencies a little easier.

Comment: I had installed the wheel from [link] (lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) and I have VCredist SP1 also but I am using Python shell.Not Anaconda python distribution.

Comment: Are you able to import gdal?

Comment: Yes. I am using gdal and it's running successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I accidentally deleted my old comment,here is the code :

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



ds = gdal.Open('filename.tif').ReadAsArray()

im = plt.imshow(ds)
```

This will work.

Comment: Perfect for a two lines quick look !

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Rasterio, but if you are looking for some library to do image analysis or just display a geotiff image, you could probably take a look at opencv python library.

Link : [OpenCV3](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/highgui/raster-gdal/raster_io_gdal.html)

Comment: But when I try to open matplotlib and opencv, the image opens but a completely dark image comes up.

Comment: Could you add your image to the post?

Answer (score 0):

TuiView is an open source PyQt-based lightweight Raster GI. Its available on Windows, Mac and Linux: http://tuiview.org